# QML force delegate instantiation

Tags: qt, delegates, qml

I have a `ListView` inside `Scrollview` and a `delegate` which instantiates items of `ListView`.

After model change I want to force instantiation of delegates for all items in the model. I use `cacheBuffer`, so instantiated items won't gone.

So the question is how can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for sounds like a good idea. Can you give a better explanation of why you think you need to force the instantiation of every item in your list? This sounds like it's probably an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JarMan let's say that's the fastest way to solve the problem, I can achieve what I want in another way, but now I am interested in this solution :)

Comment: Then I would suggest maybe using a `Repeater` instead of a `ListView`.